# How to document an archived database?

Tags: sql-server, backup

You've stored the backup file in a safe place, but what kind of info do you store with it?

- database type (SQL Server)
- compatibility level (SQL Server 2008)
- application name
- application owner
- application version

And ...?

Comment: How about the date of the backup? The version(s) of the data schema(s)? Info on references to linked databases? Any DDL/DML scripts needed to get it operational after performing a restore?

Comment: I can think of server login(s) related to database users

Answer (score 0):

I have designed  a database archiving process - which is a semi automated process.

Below are my thoughts :

Note that you have to develop your custom solution based on your organizational needs

- Create a server level trigger to track `DROP database` activity and log that activity in a table. Now if you are talking about only backup files, then you can do the same without a trigger once the backup is finished to update the table with relevant info.
- Below is the possible table structure with columns

  - ID => this will be identity column
  - TRIGGER_NAME => the name of trigger that got fired in response to the event
  - COMMENT => Friendly comment for the command that got issues e.g drop database was issued
  - EVENT_TYPE => the event type that occured e.g. `DROP_DATABASE`
  - OCCURED_DATE => the datetime when the event occured
  - SERVER_NAME => the host name
  - SERVER_INSTANCE_NAME => sql server instance name
  - PATCH_LEVEL => version info from serverproperty or you can just use `@@version`
  - LOGIN_NAME => Login that issued drop command
  - DATABASE_NAME => The database that was dropped
  - DATABASE_VERSION => If sql 2005, 2008, etc or you can use the compatibility level as well
  - COMMAND_TEXT => The command that was used for the event e.g. `drop database test_drop`
  - TYPE => I use this to differentiate between if the backup stored will be on DVD (if small) or TAPE. **This is manual bit to be updated later**.
  - TRACKING_NO => If a tracking number is assigned or a request number can be used e.g. JIRA request or HelpStar request or a TFS request number. **This is manual bit to be updated later**.
  - APPLICATION_VERISON => If your database is storing application specific version number e.g. BUILD_NUMBER or database schema version.
  - NOTIFIED => This will be default to 0 and will be updated to 1 once the DBA team is notified by an email. Once it is set to 1, the next time the job runs, it will just send out new records.
  - You can add more if needed !!

The key here is `EVENTDATA()` which has a lot of information.

Remember that triggers (whatsoever) cannot be used for backups. For backups, you have to tailor your own custom solution, but the idea remains the same.